# MQTT C++ client

Tags: c++, mqtt, libmosquitto, pahocpp

I'd like to implement an MQTT client functionality in C++ (it needs to be thread-safe, and be able to subscribe to topics and also publish, but no broker functionality is needed).

I was considering [Paho MQTT](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/) by Eclipse.
[Here](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/downloads.php) is their download page.

I find there that they don't have MQTT5.0 support.

On their [github](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.cpp) however: there is C++ wrapper which at version 1.1 states MQTTv5.0 support.

Then I have found this question: [Mosquitto vs eclipse paho client library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039471/mosquitto-vs-eclipse-paho-client-library), where the conclusion was:

> to use libmosquitto with [libmosquittopp](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/tree/master/lib/cpp) wrapper

I checked libmosquittopp.h: all functions are marked as deprecated, so I don't think it can be the right way as of now.

Why is libmosquittopp deprecated? Because

> The wrapper came about by an external request and at the time it was
>   created there were no other C++ solutions for MQTT. This has changed
>   in the past years and this wrapper provides no benefit over true C++
>   libraries or using the pure C libmosquitto.

So, is Paho now considered the right direction for using MQTT within C++?

Or I shall just use the pure C library by Mosquitto?

Or, anything else (except writing it from 0)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Paho C++ library does support MQTT v5, and is thread safe. You can publish and subscribe from multiple threads with a single client connection.

Some of the Eclipse web pages need to be updated with the latest features. The GitHub repos tend to have the latest information.

The Paho C++ lib just wraps the Paho C library, but provides an asynchronous, futures-style API, and provides memory management via shared pointers.

Answer (score 7):

If you use Boost.asio, then this project is the right choice.

https://github.com/redboltz/mqtt_cpp

It's native C++, no wrapper-around-C, and supports both v3.1.1 and v5.

Answer (score 5):

As of November 2023, there is a new kid on the block, Async.MQTT5:

https://github.com/mireo/async-mqtt5

It is also built on top of Boost.Asio, but with remarkably robust, clean and concise code. From the official documentation:

> Async.MQTT5 is a professional, industrial-grade C++17 client built on
> Boost.Asio. This client is designed for publishing or receiving
> messages from an MQTT 5.0 compatible broker. Async.MQTT5 represents a
> comprehensive implementation of the MQTT 5.0 protocol standard,
> offering full support for publishing or receiving messages with QoS 0,
> 1, and 2.
>
> Our clear intention is to include the Async.MQTT5 library into Boost.
> We are actively working on it.

Disclaimer: I work in Mireo, a company that open-sourced this MQTT client.